# BlackBerry Hyperlinks alignment

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I'm developing a BlackBerry Native Application BB SDK 5.0.

I want the Ui of this format.

--text--  --Hyperlink-- --text--
and so on.

This means i can have hyperlinks in-between the sentences.

So when i tried to make this, i'm facing some alignment issues.

Word wrap occurs and this leaves a large white space in right side of the screen.

To simulate i have attached a prototype of my code.

```
LabelField mylabel1 = new LabelField("Label 11231 23123123",LabelField.FIELD_LEFT);
         LabelField mylabel2 = new LabelField("Label2",LabelField.FIELD_RIGHT);
         LabelField mylabel3 = new LabelField("Label 312312 3123",LabelField.FIELD_RIGHT);
         LabelField mylabel4 = new LabelField("Label 41312 3123",LabelField.FIELD_RIGHT);
         LabelField mylabel5 = new LabelField("Label5",LabelField.FIELD_RIGHT);
         LabelField mylabel6 = new LabelField("Label6",LabelField.FIELD_RIGHT);
         LabelField mylabel7 = new LabelField("Label7",LabelField.FIELD_RIGHT);
         LabelField mylabel8 = new LabelField("Label8",LabelField.FIELD_RIGHT);

         FlowFieldManager hr=new FlowFieldManager(FlowFieldManager.USE_ALL_WIDTH);
         hr.add(mylabel1);
         hr.add(mylabel2);
         hr.add(mylabel3);
         hr.add(mylabel4);
         hr.add(mylabel5);
         hr.add(mylabel6);
         hr.add(mylabel7);
         hr.add(mylabel8);
         add(hr);
```

Comment: check this which is related to your question http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/How-to-Extend-Manager/ta-p/446749

Comment: Fixing alignment in this case seems too hard using available UI components. You need to write custom hyperlink field from the scratch. Other option is, you can create a HTML code with all the links, and load the HTML within a `BrowserField`.